# NameError: name 'startCommand' is not defined - PYTHON

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
from telegram import ParseMode
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, Defaults, Updater

COINBASE_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
COINBASE_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' 
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

coinbase_client = Client(COINBASE_KEY, COINBASE_SECRET)

#if __name__ == '__main__':
updater = Updater(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN, defaults=Defaults(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler('start', startCommand) # Accessed via /start
dispatcher.add_handler('alert', priceAlert) # Accessed via /alert

updater.start_polling() # Start the bot

updater.idle() # Wait for the script to be stopped, this will stop the bot


def startCommand(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text='Hello there!')

def priceAlert(update, context):
    if len(context.args) > 2:
        crypto = context.args[0].upper()
        sign = context.args[1]
        price = context.args[2]

        context.job_queue.run_repeating(priceAlertCallback, interval=15, first=15, context=[crypto, sign, price, update.message.chat_id])

        response = f"⏳ I will send you a message when the price of {crypto} reaches £{price}, \n"
        response += f"the current price of {crypto} is £{coinbase_client.get_spot_price(currency_pair=crypto + '-GBP')['amount']}"
    else:
        response = '⚠️ Please provide a crypto code and a price value: \n<i>/price_alert {crypto code} {> / &lt;} {price}</i>'

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=response)


def priceAlertCallback(context):
    crypto = context.job.context[0]
    sign = context.job.context[1]
    price = context.job.context[2]
    chat_id = context.job.context[3]

    send = False
    spot_price = coinbase_client.get_spot_price(currency_pair=crypto + '-GBP')['amount']

    if sign == '<':
        if float(price) >= float(spot_price):
            send = True
    else:
        if float(price) <= float(spot_price):
            send = True

    if send:
        response = f' {crypto} has surpassed £{price} and has just reached <b>£{spot_price}</b>!'

        context.job.schedule_removal()

        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=response)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b9dm.png)

I get this error of the code above, also I have already tried changing the position of the  `def` but, it also shows error, How to solve this?
It is the code for telegram bot and also this keeps on showing me NameError, I have already added python3 and pip, but still not solved

Comment: You can't refer to a function name before the function is defined. Put the function definitions at the beginning.

Comment: I know you say you tried changing the position, but you must not have put it in the correct position. Try again.

Comment: Have you tried moving all functions to just after the imports?

Comment: File "bot.py", line 59, in <module>
    dispatcher.add_handler('start', startCommand) # Accessed via /start
  File "/home/ishaan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 501, in add_handler
    raise TypeError(f'handler is not an instance of {Handler.__name__}')
TypeError: handler is not an instance of Handler


It shows this error if moved after imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python reads files top to bottom. So when you call `dispatcher.add_handler('start', startCommand)`, the function `startCommand` is not yet known. Move the part

```
updater = Updater(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN, defaults=Defaults(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler('start', startCommand) # Accessed via /start
dispatcher.add_handler('alert', priceAlert) # Accessed via /alert

updater.start_polling() # Start the bot

updater.idle() # Wait for the script to be stopped, this will stop the bot
```

below the callback definitions.

Apart from that, `add_handler` needs a `Handler` as argument, in your case something like `add_handler(CommandHanlder('start', startCommand)`. Please see [PTB tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) as well as [the examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples).

---

Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of the `python-telegram-bot` library.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dispatcher.add_handler('start', startCommand()) # Accessed via /start
dispatcher.add_handler('alert', priceAlert()) # Accessed via /alert
```

You will also need to add the two arguments required by both functions.

```
dispatcher.add_handler('start', startCommand(update, context))
dispatcher.add_handler('alert', startCommand(update, context))
```

I'm not exactly sure what data the two functions take in but I'm going to guess that it is whatever the bot is returning.

Comment: That's not how `add_handler` works. Please see the [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.add_handler) for details.